# Mysql Partitioning based on time reference

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to partition a log table that uses bigint to store a unix time stamp instead of datetime, and I want mysql to only keep the most recent 30 days worth of logs in a given partition. I know I can partition initially based on existing data, but how do I get mysql to persistently only keep the most recent 30 days worth of records in the log?

The logic for partitioning doesn't seem to support the idea. Am I left to create a schedule that repartitions the data every week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a schedule to repartition the data, yes. You could also attach a trigger to an insert in your table and do the repartitioning that way. It would be done automaticly. Either way, I'm pretty sure you'll need to code something because it won't be done automaticly.

A third way would be to have a view and call it. Your table would contain all the data but the view would only return the data you want to see dynamicaly.